# A neural networks with two outputs

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I am new to Keras and would like to build a neural network with two outputs.
 Basically, what I do is that I set the Dense function of the last layer to 2 just as follows

```
model.add(Dense(2, activation = 'relu',kernel_initializer=RandomNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.05, seed=0)))
```

is that correct?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unclear what you mean by two outputs. As far terminology goes your network *has a single output of size 2* because you output a single vector. We can argue this is multi-output in the sense that you have 2 values you are computing but technically we would refer to as single output. It depends on what your application is.

Actual multi-output networks are built using the [functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) where you have a list of vectors/tensors as output from different layers. In this case you can for example:

```
out1 = Dense(2, activation='relu')(in)
out2 = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(in)
model = Model(in, [out1, out2])
```

which will have 2 vectors as output. How is this different from `Dense(5)`? Well now we have different activations and trying to predict a regression as well as a classification of input in this example which you can't do effectively with a single vector output.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to achieve is to get two different outputs from your neural network, then that implementation is wrong. In that line of code you are creating two neurons in that Dense layer, so like if you are trying to predict the class of your input out of the two classes, in a multi-class classification problem, then you are doing it right (just change activation='softmax')

But, if what you are trying to do is predict two different outputs from single neural network, then you will have to use Keras's Model api, and then basically and then create different output layers for each output and pass them as a list while instantiating the model.

If you are new to Keras, I would highly recommend to go through this [book](https://www.manning.com/books/deep-learning-with-python), it would really help.

Comment: Thank you very much. yes, what I actually want to do is to predict two different outputs from a single neural network. I switched to the Model api as you suggested, now when I run this command out1 = Dense(1, activation='relu')(X) 
I get this error  "Layer dense_2 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor" , I was wondering what I am doing wrong ?